# can't get specific value in XML asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, xml-parsing

I am getting an XML object from http POST. the XML looks like this.

```
<GetTransactionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Errors xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO"/>
      <TransactionStatusCode>Completed</TransactionStatusCode>
      <Transaction xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO">
            <a:AmountPaid>5.00</a:AmountPaid>
             ....
      </Transaction>
 </GetTransactionResponse>
```

this is my code to retrieve the XML:

```
Dim x: Set x = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
x.Open "GET", "http://localhost/tutorial/poli/success.php?token=2uBddM5Mw0ip91Wx7akcuT5btzwoxRUM", false
'x.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
x.Send()

If x.status = 200 Then
    Dim docXML
    Set docXML = server.CreateObject( "MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0" ) 
    docXML.async = False 
    docXML.loadXML( x.responseText )    
    docXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.Contracts'"
```

now I can get the data from `AmountPaid` as following:

```
dim obj1
set obj1 = docXML.selectSingleNode( "//a:AmountPaid" )
Response.write obj1.text
```

but when i get the the `TransactionStatusCode` I failed with error 'Object required`
this how I try to get it:

```
dim obj1
set obj1 = docXML.selectSingleNode( "/TransactionStatusCode" )
Response.write obj1.text
```

please explain to me why it didnt work out, and how to get it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with highly structured XML, you should use full pathes in XPath queries, e.g.

```
set obj1 = docXML.selectSingleNode( "/GetTransactionResponse/TransactionStatusCode" )
```

The 'catch all' "//whatever" is appropriate for less structured XML (perhaps .xhtml documents), where the whatevers can be found on different levels/everywhere.

So **don't** add the missing "/" in your

```
set obj1 = docXML.selectSingleNode( "/TransactionStatusCode" )
```

**Update wrt comments:**

Yes, it is a namespace problem - according to [How to use XPath to query against a user-defined default namespace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288147/en-us) it is all by design.

You need to give a name to the default namespace in the "SelectionNamespaces" property and use tha name in your queries. In code:

```
Option Explicit

  Dim sXML : sXML = Join(Array( _
      "<GetTransactionResponse xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.Contracts"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">" _
    , "<Errors xmlns:a=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO""/>" _
    , "<TransactionStatusCode>Completed</TransactionStatusCode>" _
    , "<Transaction xmlns:a=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO"">" _
    , "     <a:AmountPaid>5.00</a:AmountPaid>" _
    , "</Transaction>" _
    , "</GetTransactionResponse>" _
  ), vbCrLf)

' !! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288147/en-us
  Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
' Dim sNS : sNS = "xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.Contracts'"
  Dim sNS : sNS = "xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.DCO' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:wtf='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centricom.POLi.Services.MerchantAPI.Contracts'"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", sNS
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.loadxml sXml
  If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
     WScript.Echo "ready to process"
     Dim sXPath
     For Each sXPath In Array( _
          "/GetTransactionResponse/TransactionStatusCode" _
        , "/wtf:GetTransactionResponse/wtf:TransactionStatusCode" _
        , "/wtf:GetTransactionResponse/wtf:Transaction/a:AmountPaid" _
     )
       Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = oXDoc.SelectSingleNode(sXPath)
       If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
          WScript.Echo sXpath, "not found"
       Else
          WScript.Echo sXpath, "=>", ndFnd.text
       End If
     Next
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXDoc.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
cscript 21299850.vbs
ready to process
/GetTransactionResponse/TransactionStatusCode not found
/wtf:GetTransactionResponse/wtf:TransactionStatusCode => Completed
/wtf:GetTransactionResponse/wtf:Transaction/a:AmountPaid => 5.00
```

Comment: unfortunately, still not working. it doesn't make sense why it isn't! do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a namespace issue?

Comment: Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner ill look at it.
@oraclecertifiedprofessional I believe it is namespace issue, but I tried the same method using PHP and i retrieved `TransactionStatusCode` just fine. however the inner tags of `Transaction` needs namespace. while in asp classic I couldn't get the `TransactionStatusCode`

Comment: OMG I didn't notice the alert of the question. I've just noticed it now. it works fine now. thanks for your hard work.